# Object Oriented Programming accessing variable values, How to?

Tags: php

I am a learner, I have a class **db** to help me connect and fetch results in mySQL.

```
$set = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM users");
echo $set->name;
```

this way i use echo results outside a class.

Now i have created another class name **user** and it has this function

```
public function name() {
            global $db;
            $set = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM users");
            $this->name = $set->name;
    }
```

after initializing the class user, when i try to echo **$user->name** i dont get expected results.

Note i have declared above **var $name;** in class **user**

Comment: For one thing, using `var` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DB
{
    public function get_row($q)
    {
        # do query and store in object
        return $object;
    }
}

class User
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name();
    }

    public function name() {
        global $db;
        $set = $db->get_row("SELECT * FROM users");
        echo "<pre>".print_r($set)."</pre>"; # make sure $set is returning what you expected.
        $this->name = $set->name;
    }
}

$db = new DB();
$user = new User();
echo $user->name;
```

Comment: Were you missing the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty concerned by several things I see here

1. The method name `name()` is terribly uncommunicative as to what the method is supposed to do. Remember, methods are *actions* - try to give them some sort of verb in their name.
2. Usage of `global` in a class (or even usage of `global` *period*) when you should be using [aggregation or composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation).
3. You don't show any execution examples, but I can only assume you never actually call `User::name()`, which is why your test is failing

Here's some code that addresses these concerns.

```
<?php

class DB
{
  /* Your methods and stuff here */
}

class User
{
  protected $db;
  protected $name;

  public function __construct( DB $db )
  {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    if ( is_null( $this->name ) )
    {
      $set = $this->db->get_row( "SELECT * FROM users" );
      $this->name = $set->name;  
    }
    return $this->name;
  }
}

$db = new DB();

$user = new User( $db );
echo $user->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very much sorry, i figured out that problem was on my part, i was using cookies and had two cookies set which were giving problems :(